# Input Value lies outside of the range

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

The following control problem is formulated using Lagrangian equation. I spent a lot of time to get rid of the "warning: input value lies outside the range..." and this is my last resort and help is needed to solve the problem.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Needs["VariationalMethods`"];  
SetSystemOptions["CheckMachineUnderflow" -> False];

gdp = 1;   
AA = 25;                  
μ = .01;
β = .20;
γ = .056;
ρ = .05;   
θ = .99;                     
λ = .20;

(*minimize objective function by choosing n0[t]=control variable*)
Obj[t_]=Exp[-ρ*t]*gdp*(n0[t]*(SS[t]+RR[t])+(μ*AA +λ* (1-μ))*II[t]);

(*Dynamics of state equations or feasibility conditions*)
const1[t] = D[SS[t], t] + β*SS[t]*II[t]*(1-θ*n0[t])^2;
const2[t] = D[II[t], t] - β*SS[t]*II[t]*(1-θ*n0[t])^2 +
            (μ + γ)*II[t];
const3[t] = D[RR[t], t] - γ*II[t];

(*Lagrangian function*)
Lagrange[t]=(Obj[t]+m1[t]*const1[t]+m2[t]*const2[t]+m3[t]*const3[t]);
eulerLagrange = 
  EulerEquations[
     Lagrange[t], {SS[t], II[t], RR[t], m1[t], m2[t], m3[t]}, t] // 
     FullSimplify
 boundary = {SS[0] == 0.999, II[0] == 0.001, RR[0] == 0, m1[0] == 0.1, 
            m2[0] == .3, m3[0] == 0};

(*optimal path of control n0[t] minimizing Obj[t]*)
optimalN0=First@Solve[D[Lagrange[t], n0[t]] == 0, n0[t]]//FullSimplify
eqns = eulerLagrange /. optimalN0;
sol = First@NDSolve[Flatten@{eqns,boundary}, {SS, II, RR, m1, m2, m3}, {t, 0, 50}]

Plot[Evaluate[n0[t] /. optimalN0 /. sol], {t, 0, 50}]
```

I tried many different versions of this problem, and I could not solve it. First I receive the warning message in the title of this question and  plus I could not integrate the feasible interval [0, 0.7] for control variable into the problem.

Any idea for solution is welcome.

Comment: To be clear, the error regarding the input value lying outside of range is due to the fact that `NDSolve` stops integrating far short of your intended $t_{max}=50$, at only $t=1.8*10^{-7}$ possibly because of a singularity. When you then try to plot the resulting interpolating functions over the full domain of integration $0<t<50$, you get the error. So the problem lies with the method chosen by `NDSolve` not working for your problem. You will have to start there.

Comment: A couple of shots in the dark from what I recall worked for others in similar situations: you could try something like `Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}` in `NDSolve`, or increasing the `WorkingPrecision` or decreasing the `AccuracyGoal`.

Comment: @MarcoB: Thanks for your suggestions. I will try it out with your points. I am also thinking of discretizing the model to allow for jumps over the singular points. Have you tried `Discretization` before?